# angular.js view doesn't update

Tags: angularjs

I am updating an object within a resource.save callback like so:

```
$scope.addProfile = function () {
    User.save( { "id": user_id }, $scope.createdProfile, function( savedUser, getResponseHeaders ) {
        //$scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.user = savedUser;
            console.debug($scope.user); // I doublechecked that this contains the correct data 
        //});
    });
};
```

Unfortunately the view isn't updating correctly. As you can see I have already tried to wrap the thing in an apply, which results in an error "Error: $digest already in progress". Therefore i commented that bit out again.

The view bit which doesn't update looks like this:

```
<h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
{{user.location}}
...
```

The function addProfile is called from a button inside a form like so:

```
<form name='profileForm' >
    <div class="section">
        <label class="title">Name <span class="help">(required)</span>
            <textarea ng-model="createdProfile.name" ></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <button class="btn btn-large highlight" ng-disabled="!profileForm.$valid" ng-click="addProfile()">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Without seeing your controller code, it is hard to tell what the problem might be.  However, instead of `$scope.user = savedUser;`, try `angular.copy(savedUser, $scope.user)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I gave this a try, but it didn't change things. I added some more context into my description. Let me know if this helps?

Comment: It could be a scope issue (i.e., updating the wrong $scope).  Try adding `console.debug($scope)` to your save callback and add `{{$id}}` to your view.  Ensure you see the same scope ID for both.

Comment: Thanks again, this sounded like a great suggestion. It looks like I am updating the correct scope though. console debug and the id printout both have the id "005". Any more ideas?

Comment: One other idea: wrap your update to `user` in a call to `$timeout`.  If that doesn't work, then I think it is time for a jsfiddle or plunker.  Don't worry about getting resource.save to work -- you/we can replace/mock it with a call to `$timeout` to simulate the server.

Comment: Thanks, this is a brilliant idea again, which I tried and didn't work. Trying to get a jsfiddle up now.

Comment: Ok, so this is really annoying as I'm trying to get it to not work in the jsfidde, but unfortunately it's working there (http://jsfiddle.net/H7BP5/), but in my app it isn't working. If anyone has any ideas please come forward!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't defining your controller in the html.

```
<ANY ng-controller="{expression}">
...
</ANY>
```

Comment: No this isn't it. I am defining the controller, I only posted part of the code as the whole view is a bit too long to post.

Comment: Can you add a gist, jsfiddle, or plunker?